# How can I insert a ruby form into Redcloth-modified HTML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redcloth

I have a page where I use RedCloth to use markdown for the text and images.  I want to be able to place a form somewhere in the text by putting the string [Form] and my application does a substitution to replace [Form] with the ruby code to execute a Rails form.

How do I do this?  I currently executve the RedCloth-ed text with a "<%=h %>" so I don't know how to substitute a string with the Rails form code?

Thanks!

For example, in my view, I currently display a mp3 player using a gem and its helper:

```
 5 #landing_page
  6   #message
  7     = mp3_player @landing_page.mp3.url unless @landing_page.mp3_file_name.blank?
  8     = @redcloth_landing_page
```

But I actually want more flexibility in terms of being able to place this mp3 player somewhere within the redcloth document by using a substitution string {mp3}.

I'd like where the {mp3} is placed to be where the mp3 player shows up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think i understood your question correctly :D,

If you want to add a form (with html tags) as string and wish to function it as a normal form you should look in to template language like 'liquid' (https://github.com/tobi/liquid/). and it works with 'RedCloth' too

cheers

sameera

Comment: how would I insert the form using rails code instead of hand-coding the html?

Comment: Hi @Angela, check this out https://github.com/ludicast/clots.git. you can save the code in the db and use it :D

Comment: Hi @angela, check this url "https://github.com/ludicast/clots" use https, sorry the full url is not displaying here so have https in the front when type the above url

Comment: Hi, I tried this and its still not going there and it has https